# Qual a diferença entre justaposição e aglutinação?

Tags: classificação-de-palavras

Quando estudamos o processo de formação das palavras, temos que os dois principais processos são a composição e derivação.

Dentro do processo de composição, temos uma sub-divisão em **justaposição** e **aglutinação**.
Qual a diferença entre eles?
Se possível, dê um exemplo de cada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

• **Justaposição:** ocorre a junção de duas ou mais palavras ou radicais, sem que haja alteração desses elementos formadores, ou seja, mantêm a mesma ortografia e acentuação que tinham antes da composição, havendo apenas alteração do significado.

Ex.: **Para-raios**, **corre-corre**, **guarda-roupa**, **segunda-feira**, **girassol**.

• **Aglutinação:** ocorre a fusão de duas ou mais palavras ou radicais, havendo alteração de um desses elementos formadores. Assim, além da alteração no significado, os elementos formadores perdem sua identidade ortográfica e fonológica, havendo troca ou supressão de fonemas e apenas um acento tônico na nova palavra composta.

Ex.: **Aguardente** (água + ardente), **planalto** (plano + alto), **vinagre** (vinho + acre).